# "Focus" and activate Google Map Embed Programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm pretty new to the Google Maps API.

I'm building a simple Maps App for our TV platform here at work, the TV uses a custom webkit browser and I've confirmed that the Maps API works well on it.

Currently when you load a simple app like this on our TV (Code is given in below links):

http://markpaul.name/dont-delete/other/sample-maps-app.html

You first need to use the mouse to "click" on the screen to "focus" the map. Only after this, the map embed "activates" and you can use the up, down, left, right keys to navigate the map.

The problem I have is this; on a TV you dont have a mouse so you cant "click" to "focus"!

Is there anyway you can programatically "focus" the Google Map so I can use the arrow keys on the remote (which usually map to the keyboard up, down, left, right keys) to navigate the map?

Thanks in advance,
Mark

### UPDATE:

- My code can be seen here - http://codepen.io/newbreedofgeek/pen/EaugH
- The full screen app in codepen is here - http://codepen.io/newbreedofgeek/full/EaugH
- The hosted full screen app (minus autogenerated CodePen markup in full screen codepen view) is here - http://markpaul.name/dont-delete/other/sample-maps-app.html

Answer (score 0):

I checked you source code and my feel is that somewhere the map's position is getting changed.  So by triggering the Google map's **`resize`** it would fix your problem.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Add the above code after initializing the Google maps.  This would fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately that did not work. Basically, I need the maps app to auto-select itself and activate (you need to usually do this via a mouse click on the map itself).

Comment: I cleaned up the code and also put it on CodePen - [http://codepen.io/newbreedofgeek/pen/EaugH] (http://codepen.io/newbreedofgeek/pen/EaugH)